# Clang Mac OS X Maveric, not supporting fsanitize=undefined

Tags: macos, clang

I'm getting a segfault in my C program, and I thought I'd use Clangs help in figuring out why, as Valgrind isn't supported (yet).

I try to compile my program with -fsanitize=undefined to activiate runtime checks for undefined behaviour. All I'm getting is an error message which reads something like: "fsanitize doesn't support option 'undefined'". I've also tried using -fsanitize=address with the same result :/

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Why aren't you using a debugger to help find where the error is occurring?

Comment: What version of Xcode/clang ? Xcode 5's clang seems to recognise `-fsanitize=undefined`

Comment: @trojanfoe: The application crashes at random locations, or not at all, leading me to think that the problem is related to undefined behaviour.

I'm using the latest XCode, invoked from the command line. I seem to remember (not at the computer right now) that running `clang -v` outputs "Based on Clang 3.3-svn".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `-fsanitize` is not supported by apple's CLang.
If you go here http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.4 you can get the prebuild binaries of clang, that do recognize this option.

However this is harder because then you have to use a Makefile, 
IF by chance you use cmake, then you can just easily go to use makefiles.

**OR** replace the binaries in the Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/.../bin
**but** I don't know what can happen if you replace Apples binaries, do a backup before to be able to restore.

Honestly, I'm not myself confortable about replacing apple's binaries, because they probably added something in the clang to make it work with Xcode nicely.
Again, the GPL policy of GCC had this advantage that apple could not modify it.

-> another solution is to develop on linux,

The port to windows of CLang is on its way, but not ready yet, maybe in 3.5.

Best

Comment: Offtopic, but GCC's GPL _did_ and _does_ allow Apple to make modifications provided they publish them, but it didn't allow Apple to integrate it into Xcode. This meant always having to call executables and parsing the output (slow and error prone), slower indexing, etc. pp.